# How can I remove a blank homescreen page once I've moved all the apps off it

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

I've consolidated my 5 'pages' of apps into 3 pages.

Now I have two blank pages that have no icons in them.
These are the pages that are represented by the small squares on the home page screen that take you to these various pages that have colletions of app icons.

Having moved apps/icon to other pages, the last two pages are now blank.  How can I actually remove them?

This is a Samsung Galaxy s5 running Android 4.4

Comment: You should provide the model smartphone you use, as the techniques can differ by the particular launcher program.

Comment: Depends really, try pinching to zoom on a homescreen and see if it zooms out to show all five, then you can drag them to the bin / trashcan / x icon to remove. It really depends on device / launcher though. Those aren't pages of apps by the way, those are homescreens. You can add shortcuts to apps, or widgets etc (very useful). The actual list of apps is in the 'app drawer' usually accessed by pressing the bottom middle icon in the dock (often has a picture of lots of little squares). If you can't delete them look into some useful widgets (calendars, weather, notes, reminders etc)

Comment: Added phone model info and android version.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried pinch-zooming out but it didn't do it.

Comment: Wait I tried pinch-zooming out again (on a different home page) and it worked!  Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found that if I went to one of the blank screens and then pinched out from there, I was able to see a trash can at the top and then I could move that empty page into it.

Comment: Please accept your answer if it is correct. Also please edit your answer to include a reference that the correct steps where from @RossC

Comment: I'm down voting because you took what RossC posted as a comment and used it as your own answer without giving him credit or to ask whether he could post it as the answer. Bad manners. His comment stated "home screens" which includes blank/empty ones.

Answer (score 2):

Go in your home sreen, push the settings button for 1-2 seconds or try to zoom, and then all your pages will appear, now you will be able to delete the pages you don't need anymore by clicking on delete or maybe there is a button in the top right corner.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

For Xiaomi MI-4, to remove additional blank home screens, put three fingers in blank home screen. And swipe slowly to left and right. This will bring all the home sceen in one sceen with option to delete It and add as well. I did the same way and deleted 5 blank home screens.
thanks.